# Congratulations on 1 million users! 

Tags: discussion

I just saw this a few minutes ago, saying you guys had 1,000,720 total users! I'm assuming this happened recently, so I though I'd bring it to attention!

[image]

This is a really good site that helps so many every day, no wonder so many people are here, well done!

Comment: thanks. it's all because of the community :)

Comment: Now I have official confirmation I ***am*** one in a million. ;))

Comment: Isn't that great? [They say](https://www.worldometers.info/) that there are around 7,858,537,979 persons in the whole world. That means that the "_Super-User_" Base of around 1,000,720 persons is representing around 0,013% of the population of the whole world. That makes me feel so very, very special. I really love this site.

Comment: @MihaiDobrescu 1 human may have >1 SU accounts.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt Let's not spoil the fantasy.